# Continuity in terms of lines

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mg.metric-geometry

Let $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, where $n> 1$ be a bijective map such that the image of every line is a line.

Is $f$ continuous?

I think it is, but the proof isn't immediately obvious to me.
Related to [this question on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11232/3638).

Feel free to retag.

Comment: What do you mean by "every line is mapped to a line"?  Do you mean that the restriction of $f$ to any line is linear and injective, or do you just mean that the image of every line is a line?  If you mean the latter, then it is easy to construct counterexamples even for $n=1$.

Comment: Take the second meaning, and restrict to $n > 1$, please. The original question at math.SE is about $\mathbb{R}^2$. 

Comment: Ah, I see.  That is an interesting question!

Comment: I'm sure it's standard---but what is a "line"? Is [0,1] or (0,1) a line in $\mathbf{R}$, or does a line go off to infinity in both directions?

Comment: I think that the standard terminology is that lines go off to infinity, while [0,1] and (0,1) would be segments.

Comment: For what it's worth, if we place all $\mathbf{R}$s by $\mathbf{C}$s, and consider maps from $\mathbf{C}^2$ to itself sending every affine line (something of the form $a+b\lambda$ for $a,b\in\mathbf{C}^2$ and $\lambda$ varying in $\mathbf{C}$) to an affine line, then (assuming some weak form of the axiom of choice) one can choose a discontinuous field automorphism of $\mathbf{C}$ and apply it coordinatewise to get a discontinuous map sending affine lines to affine lines. Unfortunately this automorphism must move the reals to somewhere else so can't be used in this form for the problem at hand.

Comment: @Kevin: is there a more detailed description written down somewhere in the case of $\mathbb{C}$ which you just touched on? Even that is not obvious to me. 

Comment: @Willie: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Think about it this way. Say there was a crazy discontinuous field automorphism $\sigma$ from the reals to itself. It's not hard to convince yourself (unless I made a slip) that applying $\sigma$ coordinatewise to $\mathbb{R}^n$ would give the desired map. Unfortunately no such $\sigma$ exists. However the complexes have plenty of discontinuous automorphisms, because as an abstract field the complexes are just the rationals, adjoin (size of complexes) many independent transcendentals, and then take the alg closure.

Comment: @Willie: Qing Liu's answer (which just appeared at my end) says that conversely this trick of taking field automorphisms is basically "the only trick there is" other than using affine translations.

Comment: This sort of map is called a *collineation*  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation


Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is called the fundamental theorem of affine geometry. Let $f : E \to E'$ be a map between affine spaces over a field $K$. Suppose that

1. $f$ is bijective;
2. $\dim E=\dim E'\ge 2$;
3. If $a, b, c\in E$ are aligned, then so are $f(a), f(b), f(c)$.

Then $f$ is semi-affine: fix some $a_0\in E$, then there exists a field automorphism $\sigma$ of $K$ such that the map $h: v\mapsto f(a_0+v)-f(a_0)$ (which goes from the vector space attached to ${E}$ to that attached to $E'$) is additive and $h(\lambda v)=\sigma(\lambda)h(v)$ for all $v$ and all $\lambda \in K$. I don't have an URL for this theorem, I find it in Jean Fresnel:  *Méthodes Modernes en Géométrie*, Exercise 3.5.7. But I think it is in any standard textbook on affine geometry.

When $K=\mathbb R$, it is known that $K$ has no non-trivial field automorphism. So your $f$ is an affine function, hence continuous. If $K=\mathbb C$, as pointed out by Kevin in above comments, take any non-trivial automorphism of $\mathbb C$, then you get a semi-affine map $\mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n$ which will not be affine, even not continuous (if $\sigma$ is not the conjugation).

Comment: Another textbook reference: M.Berger "Geometry", vol.1, section 2.6 "The fundamental theorem of affine geometry".


Comment: Yes, <a href="http://books.google.com/books?id=5W6cnfQegYcC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=fundamental+theorem+in+affine+geometry&source=bl&ots=S1tAxIJrC-&sig=rmaBT9L6JyHumzwusKM9uHcE81M&hl=fr&ei=S4npTOhN1IqFB-29uA8&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=fundamental%20theorem%20in%20affine%20geometry&f=false">here is a link.</a>